# ordering of executing preinst and config scripts

Tags: apt, package-management, packaging

Is it possible to force some preinst script to run before another?

What I would like to do, is create a package in my private repository, which when installed would FIRST ask some questions, and only then other packages (on which it depends) would be unpacked.

For example, let's say I want to create `my-mysql` package, which would depend on `mysql-server-5.5` from standard repository. I would like when user types `apt-get install my-mysql` for `my-mysql.preinst` to run before `mysql-server-5.5.preinst` (so it can do `debconf-set-selections` to autogenerate root password and to stop mysql-server package from asking for it interactively).

I could do it without putting any depends in `my-mysql` package, and manually running two commands:

```
apt-get install my-mysql
apt-get install mysql-server-5.5
```

but I need it to work with only one command (`apt-get install my-mysql`). I've tried playing with `Pre-depends` on third package which would do config, and `Depends` on mysql-server-5.5, but it seems `mysql-server-5.5.preinst` always run first. Is there a way to change that and force my package preinst to run before it?

As alternative way, I also cannot run `apt-get install mysql-server-5.5` from postinst because of dpkg locking issues, and would like to do it in much cleaner way than [locking kludges like this one.](https://gist.github.com/chilicuil/74fddda2a31bba09b973)

UPDATE: as mentioned in the comments, it seems that mysql-server package also has `.config` scripts (with associated `.templates`) which execute even before `.preinst` scripts, so I need to order them too.

Comment: I checked `mysql-server-5.5`, and it asks for the password in `postinst`, not `preinst`. I'd suggest you check whether your `preinst` is correctly setting the password debconf selection.

Comment: @muru I'm pretty sure. I've set `DEBIAN_SCRIPT_DEBUG` and `apt-get install my-mysql` says as a first thing `Preconfiguring packages ...
+ DEBIAN_SCRIPT_TRACE=1
${DEBIAN_SCRIPT_TRACE:+ echo "#42#DEBUG# RUNNING $0 $*" 1>&2 }
+ echo '#42#DEBUG# RUNNING /tmp/mysql-server-5.5.config.WdEe3A configure ' '1>&2'`. Only later does `my-mysql.preinst` does its output.

Comment: Pretty sure of what? That your `preinst` is setting the password correctly? The output you show doesn't indicate anything to that effect.

Comment: @muru shortened Output shows that the *first thing* apt-get runs is mysql-server-5.5.config. Only after that is completed, does it run my-mysql.preinst script (first line of which outputs some text, so I know exactly when it is run). Since my-mysql.preinst is run only **AFTER** mysql-server already asked the password question, it does not matter what my-mysql.preinst does or does not do correctly, as it is already too late.

Comment: That's because *that* prompt is from a `config` script, not a `preinst` script. You might try running your own `config` script, but the timing of `config` isn't guaranteed, so there's no telling if it will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a way to do it.

So, in order for single `apt-get install my-mysql` to work as described in question, I had to do several things:

- make `my-mysql` package so it pre-depends on `my-mysql-config` and depends on `mysql-server`
- create additional package `my-mysql-config`, which pre-depends on `debconf` and contains `my-mysql-config.templates` and `my-mysql-config.config` script (which among other things sets password so mysql-server-5.5 won't ask for it) containing code like:

  ```
  . /usr/share/debconf/confmodule
  db_set  mysql-server/root_password "$PW"
  db_fset mysql-server/root_password seen true

  db_set  mysql-server/root_password_again "$PW"
  db_fset mysql-server/root_password_again seen true
  ```
- also `my-mysql-config.preinst` contains code that does `db_get` and creates config files *before* mysql-server gets started
- you can use `my-mysql` package `.postinst` script to run stuff you want after mysql-server is installed and running.

[The Debconf Programmer's Tutorial](http://www.fifi.org/doc/debconf-doc/tutorial.html) was great help there, as was using `export DEBCONF_DEBUG=developer` and `set -x` in scripts for debugging.

Another two time-consuming issues for debug was making sure that config/preinst/postinst scripts do not output ANYTHING to STDOUT (as it breaks debconf in strange and interesting ways) and that you need `db_stop` if you do stuff like `invoke-rc.d mysql restart` or similar (or your apt-get will hang hard, without even responding to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>)